# How can we use Feature Importance to Find the 'Worst' Features?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, feature-selection

I have some data at work that is confidential so I can't share it here, but the dataset below illustrates the point quite well. Basically, I want to run a feature importance exercise to find the top independent features (in this case, RM, LSTAT, and DIS) that have the most influence on the dependent feature (MDEV). This is done! My question is...how can I use this model to find the IDs associated with the top independent features (RM, LSTAT, and DIS)?

**After viewing the plot, is it simply sorting the dataframe, in descending order, by RM, LSTAT, and DIS, because these are the top most influential features that impact the dependent feature? I don't think it works like that, but maybe that's all it is. In this case, I am assuming RM, LSTAT, and DIS are the 'worst' features, given the context of my business needs.**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV, LassoCV, Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

#Loading the dataset
x = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(x.data, columns = x.feature_names)
df["MEDV"] = x.target
X = df.drop("MEDV",1)   #Feature Matrix
y = df["MEDV"]                #Target Variable
df.head()

df['id'] = df.groupby(['MEDV']).ngroup()
df = df.sort_values(by=['MEDV'], ascending=True)
df.head(10)

names = df.columns
reg = RandomForestRegressor()
reg.fit(X, y)
print("Features sorted by their score:")
print(sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), reg.feature_importances_), names), reverse=True))

features = names
importances = reg.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)

plt.title('Feature Importances')
plt.barh(range(len(indices)), importances[indices], color='#8f63f4', align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), features[indices])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that you already solved your question yourself. If you sort by how  influential features are, the least important will be first and the most important will be last, so RM is most important and ZN is least important. Are you asking this or something else?

Comment: That's sort of what I thought, but I felt like there may be more to it. Didn't know if I was missing something. So, essentially, it's just this line of code...

df_sort = df.sort_values(['LSTAT', 'RM', 'DIS'], ascending = [False, False, False])
df_sort.head(20)


That shows me the top 20 'worst' records, right. In my case, the 'worst' is the most most expensive, because these circuit IDs go down the most frequently, and cost the power company the most in lost revenue. That's the problem I am trying to solve. Is this right????

Comment: No, feature importance tells you which features are important for the model's prediction, but not in which direction.